# Dynamic dispatch in Elixir in this way

Tags: elixir

I want to create a function with implementation which I'll embed in other modules, **without having to re-implement it in those**. It'll be something like this:

```
defmodule MyModuleWithFunction do
  def my_function(m) do
    IO.puts("***my name: #{__MODULE__}. My current value: #{m.var1}")
  end
end

# usage 1
defmodule M1 do
  def var1 do
    "M1 var1"
  end

  # somehow embed my_function() here without having to re-implement it
end

# usage 2
defmodule M2 do
  def var1 do
    "M2 var1"
  end

  # somehow embed my_function() here without having to re-implement it
end

defmodule Main do
  def print_data do
    M1.my_function()
    M2.my_function()
  end
end
```

===>

```
"***my name: M1. My current value: M1 var1"
"***my name: M2. My current value: M2 var1"
```

I'm aware of behaviours and protocols. However, how can I *embed* `my_function` in other modules and make it work in the desired way?

Comment: You are calling external modules just right,  it's in the communicating/passing of variables that you are being unidiomatic.  If you really want to maintain an object orientated approach you might instead spawn a process for each  'object'/variable and ask for it's value by message passing using send and receive. But it preferable to change idiom if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question stated in the title.

Dynamic dispatch in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) might be achieved with [`Kernel.apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#apply/3).

Answer (score 0):

**Beware:** I strongly discourage you from doing this unless you perfectly understand how it works.

To get access to the `__MODULE__` variable in the way you want, you need the AST to be injected rather than the function be called. That said, you need a macro, not a regular function.

```rb
defmodule Injected do
  defmacro yo do
    caller = __CALLER__.module
    quote do
      IO.puts("***my name: #{unquote(caller)}. My current value: #{unquote(caller).var}")
    end
  end
end
```

And, in the target module:

```rb
defmodule M do
  def var do
    "M1 var1"
  end

  import Injected

  def test, do: yo()
end
```

That makes it possible to *call* you function inside a module, but not from outside because both functions and macros get imported as *private*.

---

To achieve what is needed, one might use [`Kernel.use/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#use/2).

```rb
defmodule Used do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    caller = __CALLER__.module

    quote do
      def yo do
        IO.puts("***my name: #{unquote(caller)}. My current value: #{unquote(caller).var}")
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule M do
  use Used

  def var do
    "M1 var1"
  end
end

M.yo()
#⇒ ***my name: Elixir.M. My current value: M1 var1
```

Comment: I'm aware about macros. Since they should be  used with caution and avoided whenever possible, is there a better way to achieve what I want to?

Comment: If you want to get to the context of the calling module, you need to inject AST, hence macros are unavoidable. If you want to simply reuse a function, do call it. There is no “better” way, and you still have not stated clearly what do you want to achieve.

Comment: And you won't know what I want to achieve because it doesn't matter to you. All you need to know is in my question

Comment: That said, you are unable to understand the answer? OK.